# How do I compare fractions to find duplicates and only add the unique fractions to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, fractions

I am trying to compare two fractions here. One of them is read in from a file and then given to num and denom and the other is every two indices of the array "allFracs".

I need to compare each num and denom to make sure they are unique and not duplicates that are already in "allFracs".

I found that I can do this by cross-multiplying the fractions and then setting a boolean variable to true/false based on whether it exists or not. If the boolean is still false and the array has enough room in it, then I would set allFracs[count] and allFracs[count + 1] equal to num and denom and increment count by 2.

My problem is that the fractions that equal the same things (i.e. 4/2 and 6/3) still appear in the array. *Please do not answer with professional solutions, as I will not understand them.

```
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] frac = input.nextLine().split("/");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(frac[0]); 
        int denom = Integer.parseInt(frac[1]); 
        boolean doesExist = false;
        if (totalElements == 0)
        {
            allFracs[0] = num; 
            allFracs[1] = denom; 
            totalElements++; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < totalElements; index += 2)              
            {
                int fraction = (num * allFracs[index + 1]) / (denom * allFracs[index + 1]);
                int fraction2 = (denom * allFracs[index] / denom * allFracs[index + 1]);    

               if (fraction == fraction2) // cross-multiplication of two fractions.
                {
                    occurences[index / 2]++;
                    doesExist = true;
                }
            }
            if (doesExist == false) 
            {
                if (count + 2 >= allFracs.length - 1)
                {
                    allFracs = resizeArray(allFracs);
                    allFracs[count] = num;
                    allFracs[count + 1] = denom;
                }
                else
                {
                    allFracs[count] = num;
                    allFracs[count + 1] = denom;
                }
            }
        }
        count += 2; // incrementing for both the numerator and denominator.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare if two fractions `a/b` and `c/d` are equal you check for `a*d == c*b`, which in your code would be:

```
if (num*allFracs[index + 1] == allFracs[index]*denom) 
{
  occurences[index / 2]++;
  doesExist = true;
}
```